# How to set android.enableAapt2=false in Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova-plugins

I am using android platform version 7 in my Cordova Project. But due to some reasons, I want to set `android.enableAapt2=false`. 
Can someone share the knowledge for achieving the above purpose?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new file titled `gradle.properties` with that line in it. Alternatively, edit the file if it exists.

```
echo android.enableAapt2=false >> platforms/android/gradle.properties
```